# Payout amount dependent upon value for each person in population

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation

I am a software developer tasked with solving a problem programmatically, but I'm limited in what I remember about statistics and am not sure how to properly word my question to search for the answer.  Thanks in advance for your help.

**Problem**
I have a list of people that each have a particular salary amount.  I also have a bucket of money.  I want to distribute the bucket of money to everyone based on their salary, ***with the lowest earners getting the highest amount and the highest earners getting the least***.

**Example**

- Person A - $4.00
- Person B - $5.00
- Person C - $6.00
- Person D - $20.00

The bucket of money is $100.00

FYI, my dataset is made up of almost 3000 records, so the above example is very simplified.

Is there a formula/algorithm that can help me figure this out ?

Comment: Don't you have any more constraints?  In the example, we could give A the whole $\$100$.  Or we could give him $\$97$, B $\$2$, C $\$1$, and D nothing.  Obviously, there are many, many solutions, so more conditions are needed in order to pick one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  There really aren't, I'm just trying to "fairly" distribute the money to those who are most in need.  I got close by calculating the standard deviation, but I ended up with a lot of negative dollar amounts - i.e. people would have to "pay in" to the bucket, which obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, I suggest producing a column of the "deficits", i.e. the distance between a given person's salary and the max.  Thus in your table you'd have $(16,15,14,0)$.  Now give each person $\lambda$ times their deficit for a fixed constant $\lambda$ set so that the sum is the total money to be distributed.    In your case we'd get $\lambda = 2.\overline 2$   This distribution has the property that, if my deficit is twice yours, I get twice as much cash out of the pot.

Comment: @lulu - Thank you for your help.  I understand part of what you're saying, but I'm getting lost in the last two sentences (i.e. starting with "now five each person...").  Are you able to explain a little more.  I'm pretty limited in my statistical understanding.

Comment: "five" was a typo for "give" (now corrected).   There is no statistics in this problem.  To check your understanding, with my distribution method and your data I would give $A$ $35.\overline 5$, I'd give $B$ $33.\overline 3$ and $C$ would get $31.\overline 1$     $D$ of course gets nothing (though you could easily modify the method to give $D$ something if you wanted).

Comment: I should say:  my distribution will crash in the case in which every single person has the same salary (since all the deficits are $0$ in that case).  If you want to avoid that, then instead of taking the deficit from the max, take the deficit from the max plus some positive constant.  This will also ensure that the max salary people get something, though it slightly distorts the scale property that my original distribution has (though I have no idea if that property matters to you or not).

Comment: @lulu  Thank you for your replies.  Your recommendation seemed similar (to a novice like me) to the answer below, so between both of your replies I was able to make my logic work.  As I said on the answer, you've made a significant number of people very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try making it proportional to the reciprocal of the person's earnings.  In the example, we have $$S=\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac1{20}=\frac23$$

So then A would get $$\frac{1/4}{2/3}=\frac38=37.5\%$$ of the pot, B would get $30\%$, C would get $25\%$ and D would get $7.5\%$.

There's no way to defend this mathematically, of course.  It does guarantee that persons earning less get more of the pot, though.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked great!  I had to modify it slightly as your logic exposed some holes in mine.  Thank you - you just made a lot of people very happy.

Comment: @JayTaplin Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

From your reply to the first comment, I think you are not only looking for an algorithm but also for an argument for your decision on how to distribute the bucket.

I suggest you use a Lorenz curve. First, order the individuals in ascending order, from the one with the lowest salary to the one with the highest and get the cummulative proportion of your population. Use this line, which is of length one, as your x-axis. Second, for each point in x, locate the cummulative wealth that corresponds to the cummulative population in your y-axis. You will end up with a figure similar to the following

### [image: Lorenz Curve]

A line of 45 degrees would represent equality among your individuals. Then, from the several alternatives of distribution you have, choose the one which makes the new wealth distribution more equal.